# can I embed git tag in pycharm source or otherwise version stamp python source?

Tags: python, pycharm

I want to "version stamp" a python source file, preferably with the current git tag? I use pycharm. This is so I can easily find out what version I have distributed to someone, distribution is currently fast and informal.

Comment: Are you looking for this: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/adding-tags.html?

Comment: What do you mean by 'version stamp' a source file ? And are you distributing a single file each time, or a whole package ?

Comment: ideally I would like to assign a variable to the current git tag, via some kind of macro e.g. version = CURRENT_GIT_TAG ... the sort of thing preprocessor macros can do